# Will I receive notifications if someone repeatedly tries to access my Facebook account in an attempt to discover my password?

Tags: facebook

If that is the case, would it be possible for me to ascertain the **identity** of the individual making repeated attempts to access my Facebook account?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Web Applications is not a help/service desk. Please check out the [tour] to learn the ropes of this site. It's worth tha [se] has has a site for information security professionals -> [security.se].